# Loosing ember context in callback of third party library

Tags: ember.js

I have the following code in my route for receiving webocket updates of my models.  The problem is that when this line executes

```
setTimeout(self.stompConnect, 10000);
```

I no longer have access to the Ember.Route Ember object at the top of the stompConnect method.

```
var self = this; //no longer pointing to my route
```

How can I maintain the ember context across the callback in a third pary library like this?  This has nothing to do with websockets or the library because I had the same issue with another third party library that had a callback.

I guess I need to use .bind() or something but I don't know the correct syntax.

```
stompClient : null,

activate : function() {
    this.stompConnect();
},

stompConnect : function() {
    var self = this;

    var connectCallback = function(frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/models/update', function(payload){
            var model = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(payload.body));
            var modelName = Object.keys(model)[0];
            var modelPayload = model[modelName];

            self.store.push(modelName, modelPayload);

        });
    };

    var errorCallback = function (error) {
        console.log('STOMP: ' + error);
        setTimeout(self.stompConnect, 10000); //when stompConnect() is called, the ember context is lost :(
        console.log('STOMP: Reconecting in 10 seconds');
    };

    var url = ... ;
    var socket = new SockJS(url);
    var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, connectCallback, errorCallback);

    this.set('stompClient', stompClient);
},

deactivate : function() {
    this.get('stompClient').disconnect();
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have a callback inside a callback. So context needs to be passed in both callbacks. `self` will work in errorCallBack but needs to be set again to work in `stompConnect`. I would rather suggest using `run.later` to `setTimeOut`. So Here goes the code.

```
stompClient : null,

activate : function() {
    this.stompConnect();
},

stompConnect : function() {
    var self = this;

    var connectCallback = function(frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/models/update', function(payload){
            var model = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(payload.body));
            var modelName = Object.keys(model)[0];
            var modelPayload = model[modelName];

            self.store.push(modelName, modelPayload);

        });
    };

    var errorCallback = function (error) {
        console.log('STOMP: ' + error);

        Ember.run.later(this, this.stompConnect, 1000);
        //or you can also use
        //setTimeout(this.stompConnect.bind(this), 10000); when stompConnect() is called, the ember context is lost :(
        console.log('STOMP: Reconecting in 10 seconds');
    };

    var url = ... ;
    var socket = new SockJS(url);
    var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, connectCallback, errorCallback.bind(this));

    this.set('stompClient', stompClient);
},

deactivate : function() {
    this.get('stompClient').disconnect();
}
```

I prefer using `.bind()` rather `var self = this;`. But it depends.